# Is there a formal name for an equation that has no solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

I was wondering if there is a formal name for the equations which don't have any solution?

For example consider this equation in $m$ :

$$ -2(3-m)+15=6m-4(m-20)$$

If we do the algebra we will get $2m-6m+4m=80-15+6 \Rightarrow 
0=71$ which implies no solution of $m$.

Comment: Such an equation is called "inconsistent"

Comment: @Bill Cook:But isn't "inconsistent" is for [two or more](http://www.yourdictionary.com/inconsistent-equations) equations?

Comment: Surely the equation is *insoluble*, and to be *inconsistent* it would have to be a set of equations?

Comment: I always thought the formal name was "equations with no solutions".

Comment: I see no problem using the term "inconsistent" for a single equation in the same way that a single linear equation is still a "system" of equations.

Comment: Although I guess you could argue that a system must have at least 2 equations. I think this introduces unpleasantness to theorem statements and definitions. I'd be willing to fight the definition police over that one.

Comment: Also, the term "inconsistent" does apply quite well. If the equation reduces to "0=1" then it is not consistent with itself. "Unsolvable" is ok. But this can conjure up notions of unsolvability in the sense of Galois theories etc.

Comment: The term that the textbook that we use for Algebra 1 is **"contradiction"** and the term used for an equation that has infinite solutions (4x + 2 =4x + 2) is called **"identity"**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that [*unsolvable*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unsolvable), [*insolvable*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insolvable) and [*insoluble*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insoluble) are all used in this sense.  Personally I'd prefer either of the first two, to avoid confusion with the alternative meaning of *insoluble* in physics and chemistry.

Comment: If you are not part of the solution you are part of the precipitate, as the old saying goes.

Answer (score 7):

Others have noted *inconsistent* (adj.), which may be best. Perhaps as good is *unsatisfiable* (adj.). *False* (adj.) and *a falsehood* (n.) might work, too. In basic logic, a sentence always false (like $p\wedge\neg p$) is called *a contradiction* (n.), which I suppose can be used here, too.

Answer (score 6):

According to p. 185 of *Basic Math: A Combined Version* by Williams, Miller, Salzman, and Lial (HarperCollinsCustomBooks, 1992), an equation that is a false statement for every value of the variable is an *inconsistent equation* or a *contradiction*.

Answer (score 5):

A set of equations with no solutions is called *inconsistent* if there is no simultaneous solution for the set.

It is important to note that a set containing one element is still a set, i.e.
$
0 = 71
$
is shorthand for $\{ 0 = 71 \}$ (a notation which is avoided due to obvious reasons involving tediousness of writing) and this set of equations is inconsistent.